# Parse String with Multiple Delimiters

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a field (call it `Reporting_Hierarchy`) with a value like:

`Accounting: NorthAmerica : AP: Accounts Payable`

I want to create a new field, based off of `Reporting_Hierarchy`, that only takes the text after the third colon. In this case, that would = `Accounts Payable`

What is the recommended way to do this? I have tried combinations of RIGHT/LEFT with charindex() but I am not getting exactly what I want. I know REGEX is also an option, but not sure if that is the easiest route here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split_part()`:

```
select split_part(Reporting_Hierarchy, ':', 4)
```

Comment: yup ! split_part(Reporting_Hierarchy, ':', 4) worked ... thank you!